# "Measure of time in general relativity"

Tags: general-relativity, reference-frames, metric-tensor, coordinate-systems, observers

Suppose to be in an arbitrary gravitational field and you are moving in it arbitrarily with a clock in your hand.
In this general situation I ask: if I read the positions of the hands of the clock, what am I really measuring the proper time or a simple coordinate?

Comment: A clock in your hand measures time. What the coordinates in general relativity mean is totally up to your choice of coordinates.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why do clocks measure arc-length?](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/53334/)

Answer (score 1):

You are reading the proper time (which is, of course, the value of one of many possible coordinates).

Comment: @Yildiz Indeed they will: given the curve you follow in spacetime, all observers agree on its length.

Comment: Suppose there is a strong gravitational field between you and your clock and that it varies in such a way that the light that arrives from the hands of the clock changes so you see the hands going in an irregular, non periodic way, as a normal clock shouldn't do: how is it possible that everyone will agree on this measure of "time" if this is a proper time and so a scalar?

Comment: @Yildiz: Periodicity is not a necessary requirement for a clock, only monotonicity is.

Comment: I want to be precise about this: suppose to be in an arbitrary gravitational field, what is your operative definition of "time"?

Comment: @Yildiz The proper time along a (suitably smooth) timelike curve is simply its length, which, if you know the metric, is $\int\sqrt{\pm g(\vec{\lambda}(t), \vec{\lambda}(t))}\,dt$ where $t$ parameterises the curve, and$\vec{\lambda}(t)$ is the tangent vector to the curve at $t$.

Comment: I asked how to measure, in a real and concrete way, time in general relativity using a clock: I want an operative definition that take in consideration also the presence of strong gravitational fields between me and clock, able to deviate the light that i see coming from the hands. If is not possible to give this definition how is it possible to say that the proper time is the one "measured" if i don' t have a standard definition on how to compute this measure?

Comment: @Yildiz you read what the hands on the clock say: it's as simple as that.